# Как распарсить Xml в Json node js (Vue)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron

Я не писал на node js и Vue. В основном пишу на C# но сейчас нужно сделать небольшую утелиту на Vue и Electron, нужно получить данные xml из файла и распарсить их в Json.
Казалось бы лёгкая задачка, ) но нет!
Перепробовал кучу вариантов но не чего не помогает.

```
const parser = require('p3x-xml2json');

const xml = '<foo attr="value">bar</foo>';
console.log("input -> %s", xml)

export class parserXmlToJson {    

    getXml2(){
        // xml to json
        var json = parser.toJson(xml);
        console.log("to json -> %s", json);

        // json to xml
        var xml = parser.toXml(json);
        console.log("back to xml -> %s", xml)
    }
}
```

---

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <p>{{ xmlArray }}</p>
    <button @click="parserXmlToJson()">Click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { parserXmlToJson } from '@/serverRepo/parserXmlToJson'

const parser = new parserXmlToJson();

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      xmlArray: ""
      
    };
  },
  methods: {
    parserXmlToJson() {
      parser.getXml2();      
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

пока по нажатию на кнопку в консоль должен вывестись распарсиный результат `xml`
При запуске выходит ошибка.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined
    at Object.eval (bindings.js?dfc1:29)
    at eval (bindings.js:223)
    at Object../node_modules/bindings/bindings.js (chunk-vendors.js:603)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (node-expat.js?8891:4)
    at Object../node_modules/node-expat/lib/node-expat.js (chunk-vendors.js:1787)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (xml2json.js?0821:1)
```

не понятно что не так???
Если закоментить код из класса `parserXmlToJson` и `parser.getXml2();`
Ошибок нет.
И как можно получить данные xml через файл, то есть как указать директорию где брать файл?
Который потом можно засунуть в fs и распарсить.

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: попробуйте поменять строку `const parser = require('p3x-xml2json');` на `import parser from 'p3x-xml2json' `

Comment: @Дмытрык Попробовал ошибка та же (

Comment: назад все равно не меняйте, т.к. у Вас смешаны 2 подхода к подключению модулей `require/module.exports` и `import/export`

Comment: @Дмытрык Да я так и делал по началу, это уже все варианты перебираю)))

Comment: еще, на всякий случай, библиотека `p3x-xml2json` - инсталирована? В package.json - есть?

Comment: @Дмытрык Да, всё на месте

Comment: А эта библиотека, вообще, может работать в браузере? Я скачал ее себе - получил кучу ошибок про отсутствие Python в системе

Comment: в файле `xml2json.js` замените `export class parserXmlToJson` на `class parserXmlToJson {...}; module.exports.parserXmlToJson = parserXmlToJson;`

Comment: или переименуйте его в `.ts` и замените require на import

Comment: @Дмытрык А, какая разница, я же по сути просто получаю строку. Браузер тут не причём. У меня при установки ошибок не было.

Comment: @nörbörnën `parserXmlToJson ` это мой класс, его нет в xml2json.js, причём тут TypeScript?

Comment: Если Вы не используете `vue-server-side-rendering`, то код VUE, исполняется в брайзере.

Comment: Попробуй использовать это https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-to-json-stream